# C++ Reversing Number using to_string, reverse, stoi combo giving runtime error Instance Out of Range

Tags: c++, runtime-error, reverse, outofrangeexception

Stuck trying to resolve a runtime error due to an instance out of range exception.  I'm taking the int into a string, reversing the string and returning it to int using stoi.  Simple test numbers reverse perfectly but bigger numbers are out of range.  Not sure where in the code to adjust for the out of range exception. Super stuck, please help.

```
int reverse(int x) {

    bool negFlag = false;
    if(x < 0)
    {
        negFlag = true;
    }

    string xString = std::to_string(abs(x));
    std::reverse(xString.begin(), xString.end());
    int xNum = std::stoi(xString);

    return (negFlag == true)? -xNum: xNum;
}
```

Here is the error returned:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  stoi
Last executed input:  1534236469
```

The smaller number work well.

```
Your input: 123
Output:     321
Expected:   321
```

Is there a \0 at the end of my string that is throwing everything off in the conversion? New to these C++ methods. Thanks so much. Would really love to nail these methods down and be able to use them with ease.

Vital Info:

```
Note: Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store 
integers within the 32-bit signed integer range:
```

> [-2<sup>31</sup> to +2<sup>31</sup> -1]

```
For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0 when 
the reversed integer overflows.
```

-->>  **Not sure how to formulate an if statement that will return 0; when the 32-bit is exceeded.**

Comment: `int` may be too small to hold the bigger numbers.. Try long or long long

Comment: Update changing stoi to stol resulted in wrong answer still.  Input
1534236469
Output
1056389759
Expected
0

Comment: This is exactly how `stoi` should work. It will throw an exception if the value is greater than the maximum value that an `int` can hold.

Comment: Changing the `stoi` to `stoll` may not be enough as you are still returning `int` from the function.

Comment: @jignatius ok that's good.  Should I add a check like:  if ( xNum > INT_MAX) {return 0}; to avoid a compilation error??

Comment: What does your assignment say, verbatim? Do you need to return an `int` from a function?

Comment: Given a 32-bit signed integer, reverse digits of an integer.  Example 1: Input 123 output 321:   Note:
Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−231,  231 − 1]. For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0 when the reversed integer overflows.

Comment: Reversing the digits is trivial. The gist of the assignment is detecting and/or avoiding an overflow. I do not know whether you are allowed to use standard library facilities that detect an overflow for you, such as stoi. It resembles cheating a bit too strongly to my taste, so I would avoid those. You also need to take into account that the representable range is asymmetric and abs(x) may fail.

Comment: Are you certain that the problem statement requires calculation using integers?  Any non-zero number ending with zero will not "reverse" correctly.

Comment: `"1534236469"` reversed is `"9646324351"`.   Converting that to an integral type requires more than 33 bits.    That means `stoi()` will overflow if `int` is 32 bits - which is common in practice.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse of `1,534,236,469` is `9,646,324,351`. The maximum value that a typical 32bit `int` can hold is `2,147,483,647`, so it doesn't fit into it.

You need to have your function return something larger, e.g. `long long` (which is at least 64bit) and use the appropriate conversion function for it, e.g.:

```
long long reverse(int x) {

    //...

    long long xNum = std::stoll(xString);

    //...

}
```

Whether you want to change the input type to something larger as well, depends on the maximum input value that your function is supposed to be able to process.

---

After your edit:

You can catch the conversion error and return `0` in that case (requires `#include<stdexcept>`):

```
try {
    int xNum = std::stoi(xString);
    // Maybe insert additional range test according to assignment (?)
    return (negFlag == true)? -xNum: xNum;
} catch(const std::out_of_range&) {
    return 0;
}
```

---

Assuming `int` to be 32bit two's-complement (which I understand the assignment is trying to suggest with the value range, which is presumable supposed to be `[-2**31, 2**31-1]`):

Also note that your initial call to `abs` has undefined behavior if `x == -2**31`, because `2**31` is not representable in the 32bit `int`. So you need to first make a special case for that before you call `abs` to avoid undefined behavior.

Similarly you need to consider the case where the result of the function should be `-2**31`. But you may notice that this case is irrelevant because its corresponding input value would already fall out-of-range of `int`.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the limit is 32-bit otherwise return 0 is expected.

Comment: @RedPandaRevolt This surely is the most appropriate answer I think.

Answer (score 0):

The input range is bigger than an `int` can hold. Change it to `long long` and it should work.

```
long long reverse(long long x) {

bool negFlag = false;
if(x < 0)
{
    negFlag = true;
}

string xString = std::to_string(abs(x));
std::reverse(xString.begin(), xString.end());
long long xNum = std::stoll(xString);

return (negFlag == true)? -xNum: xNum;
}
```

Note that the return type needs to be changed as well.